# How can I display a list of categories and all their posts in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working on a custom WordPress theme.

I'm trying to show a list of categories (as headings) for a custom post type, and underneath each category heading I would like to list the post titles and a single custom field. I'm using the Types plugin. I know a little php and have some WordPress experience, but not quite enough to properly figure this out.

**Example:**

> Custom Post Type: *Menu Item*
>
> Custom Field for This Post Type: *Item Price*
>
> Category: *Sandwich Fillings*
>
> Category: *Soups*
>
> Desired result:
>
> ***Sandwich Fillings***
>
> Cheese - £#.##
>
> Ham - £#.##
>
> Tuna - £#.##
>
> ...
>
> ***Soups***
>
> Tomato
>
> Chicken
>
> Vegetable

The idea will be for new categories to be added on the fly (for example, one day they might start selling melts), and for WP to iterate through the categories as new ones are added, saving from having to hard-code in new categories on the page as they are added.

Here's what I have so far:

```
<?php

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'menu-item',
        'orderby' => 'name',
        'parent' => 0
    );

    $categories = get_categories( $args );

    foreach ( $categories as $category ) {

        $posts = get_posts($args);
        $item_price = types_render_field( "item-price" );

        echo '<h2>' . $category->name . '</h2>';
        ?>
            <ul><?php
            foreach($posts as $post) {
            ?>
                <li><?php the_title(); ?>, <?php echo $item_price; ?></li>
            <?php 
        }       
    }
?>
```

What I'm getting is this:

> ***Sandwiches***
>
> Tomato,
>
> Swiss Cheese,
>
> French Brie,
>
> French Brie,
>
> ...
>
> ***Soups***
>
> Tomato, £2.60
>
> Swiss Cheese, £2.60
>
> French Brie, £2.60
>
> French Brie, £2.60

Any help would be appreciated!

***UPDATE***

This seems to have helped:

```
<?php

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'menu-item'
    );

    $categories = get_categories( $args );
    $posts = get_posts($args);


    foreach ( $categories as $category ) {



        echo '<h2>' . $category->name . '</h2>';
        ?>

        <div class="menu-items-container">
            <?php foreach($posts as $post) { ?>
                <?php $item_price = types_render_field( "item-price" ); ?>
                <?php if (in_category($category)) { ?>
                    <p><?php the_title(); ?>, <?php echo $item_price; ?></p>
                <?php  } ?>
            <?php  } ?>
        </div>
<?php } ?>
```

And it's giving me the results that I was looking for. Stumbled upon this fix through experimentation and happy accident, so I'm aware that it may not be best practice - advice or suggestions for improvement would be welcome!

Comment: Quite interesting question as it is really easy to accomplish, ***BUT*** if you choose the easy way and the more general way (*as you have done it as your solution*), it is really expensive to run. On small installation with only a few categories and post you are already running more than 100 queries, which is insane. Unfortunately I'm totally worn out by a busy day, don't have the strenght to code a working example., but your best bet is to run one query to get all posts, and the use `usort()` to sort the results according to category

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this might be better, as it does not loop through all the posts for each category:

```
<?php

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'menu-item'
    );

    $categories = get_categories( $args );

    foreach ( $categories as $category ) {

        echo '<h2>' . $category->name . '</h2>';

        $args['category'] = $category->term_id;
        $posts = get_posts($args); ?>

        <div class="menu-items-container">
            <?php foreach($posts as $post) { ?>
                <?php $item_price = types_render_field( "item-price" ); ?>
                <p><?php the_title(); ?>, <?php echo $item_price; ?></p>
            <?php  } ?>
        </div>
<?php } ?>
```